# NSProgressIndicator determinate when not in loop

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsprogressindicator

I'm using this code from another question, and can't figure out how to actually '*determine*' how long some task might take. for example:

```
- (void)doSomething
{
    [showProgress startAnimation:nil];
    dispatch_queue_t backgroundQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^{
        for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

            // Do whatever it is you need to do

            [self goUnZipFiles]; // THIS COULD BE A 1MB FILE OR 3GB

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [showProgress incrementBy:1.0];
            });
        }
        // Done with long running task
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [showProgress stopAnimation:nil];
        });
    });
}
```

The problem for example would be having a task that unzips a file that could be 1 MB or 3 GB - how can I programmatically determine how long to animate the indicator in a smooth consistent way for whatever the duration of the task might be? thanks

Comment: That depends entirely on the task itself and how it functions. Some tasks may provide you with a delegate callback you can use to track progress. Can you be more specific about what your task is and how you are accomplishing it? As a side note, your sample code calls your `goUnZipFiles` method 100 times, every time through the loop. Is this intended? I am assuming the task itself should be run once.

Comment: Thanks, the method with 100 times maybe wasn't the best example, although considering. What if I had 100 zip files that needed to be processed, how would the time be determined?